# save state activity when switch to another activity

Tags: android

I have bottom navigation in my app. Each tab of bottom navigation is activity. For example I have 3 tabs in my bottom navigation and tab 1 is activity_one, tab 2 is activity_two, tab 3 is activity_three. Every activity include some fragment.
when I switch between tabs I think activity that I selected, recreated again. I want to save state of my activity.that means when I selecet tab 1, and do some action in this tab (for example replace fragment) and switch to tab 2 and switch to tab 1, it shows last action that I've done before(fragment changed for example)
what should I do? PLEASE help me

Comment: You can call `onStop()` **OR** `onPause()`  method of fragment/Activity to save anything which u want

Answer (score 1):

you should not implement this structure in multiple activities. change your structure and replace your activities with one activity as parent Activity and you should have a frame above your bottom navigation and replace fragments in your parent activity's frame, and then you can use same fragment instance for your tabs and save your fragments state.

Comment: I've done this before. But I have one problem with it. for example, I have three tabs. tab one include fragment_1 and fragment_2. when I in tab one I navigate to fragment_2. when I switch to tab two and came back to tab one it shows fragment_1, but expect shows fragment_2.